# Mat autocomplete - Remove ID from array when user is removed

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, mat-autocomplete

I am using this autocomplete to be able to select more than one user.

When I select a user, I am storing the ids in a variable using the push. This push will help me keep the ids of all selected users.

If you select a user and then want to remove it, the push will contain that user's ID :(

Is there a way that if I delete a user, that user ID will not appear or be removed from the array fed by the push?

**Where I store all the ID's**

```
 var a = (this.nameIdMap.get(event.option.viewValue));
  this.allIDS.push(a);
   var c = this.allIDS; 
    var b = c.filter(function(value, index){ return c.indexOf(value) == index });
    console.log(b)
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jj4vcs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

**Code**

```
 remove(fruit: string): void {
    const index = this.fruits.indexOf(fruit);

    if (index >= 0) {
      this.fruits.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

 selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
  var a = (this.nameIdMap.get(event.option.viewValue));
  this.allIDS.push(a);
   var c = this.allIDS; 
    var b = c.filter(function(value, index){ return c.indexOf(value) == index });
    console.log(b)
  this.fruits.push(event.option.viewValue);
  this.fruitInput.nativeElement.value = '';
  this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
}

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.allFruits.filter(fruit => fruit.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }


<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip
      *ngFor="let fruit of fruits"
      [selectable]="selectable"
      [removable]="removable"
      (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{fruit}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input
      placeholder="New fruit..."
      #fruitInput
      [formControl]="fruitCtrl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
      [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
      [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur">
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
      {{fruit}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Problem**

As you can see, I selected 3 users and then deleted 1. In total I have 2 users selected, but in the array I have the ids of the 2 selected users + the id of the eliminated user. This deleted user id should not be present :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply to need to remove the same index from `this.allIDs` as you do from `this.fruits`

```
remove(fruit: string): void {
  const index = this.fruits.indexOf(fruit);
  if (index >= 0) {
    this.fruits.splice(index, 1);
    this.allIDS.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could create an array of objects that holds the name and ID of each entry as one object.